# How many distinct values are inside an array

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, distinct

Say you have an array like so :

`int [] myArray = 1,2,3,1,4,2,6,1,5,3,6,1;`

How can you calculate the amount of distinct values inside the array = 6 ?

Comment: Just create a `Set` out of it, and get it's size. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myArray)).size();
```

That would work if `myArray` is of type `Integer[]`. In your case, the simplest way to do it is to iterate over each element and add it to the set:

```
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
for(int i : myArray) set.add(i);
int i = set.size();
```

Comment: what;s the diiferent between `TreeSet` and `Set` used below ?

Comment: @hayonj Not big difference in your case. Search for `programming to interface`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get all the *distinct* values by converting your array into a `Set`, which is a collection that  cannot contain duplicates.

```
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestSet { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      int [] myArray = new int[]{ 1,2,3,1,4,2,6,1,5,3,6,1 };
      Set<Integer> s = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(myArray));

      // count distinct values
      System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(myArray) + " has " 
                         + s.size() + " distinct values");
   }
}
```

Comment: what;s the difference between a collection and an array ?

Comment: whats the difference between .length() and .size() ?

Comment: @hayonj In Java a *collection* is anything that inherits from the `Collection<E>` interface. An array is a *more* primitive container than anything from collection because it doesn't have methods that can be called on it directly. `length` is an *attribute* of an array, `size()` is a method of the `Collection<E>` interface that all collections have to implement.

Comment: Why a `TreeSet`? OP doesn't specifically require displaying in order.

Comment: @fge For an example this small I don't think it really matters what concrete `Set` I chose. `TreeSet` was the first I thought of.